# Adding empty object and array

Tags: javascript

I apologize in advance because this is somehow a silly question, but I just need to know WHY this happens and I didn't find the answer. So, there you go, stack overflow!

In this [video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) (which I can't recommend enough) around 2:00 mark the guys shows that in Javascript:

```
[] + [] = empty string
[] + {} = object
{} + [] = 0
{} + {} = NaN
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: JavaScript is both fascinating and frightening... +1

Comment: JS has ALL SORTS OF implicit conversions based on the operator.  JavaScript guru coming to explain each in 5...4...3..

Comment: `[] + {}` is the string representation of an object, which is usually something like "[object Object]" http://jsconsole.com/?typeof%20(%5B%5D%20%2B%20%7B%7D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This blog post](http://blog.caplin.com/2012/01/27/the-why-of-wat/) by [Adam Iley](http://blog.caplin.com/author/adamicaplincom/) covers the reasoning behind most of those edge cases.

(Note: The site is having some database problems. You can use the [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://blog.caplin.com/2012/01/27/the-why-of-wat/&hl=en&strip=1) until they fix things.)